# How to redirect to settings/preferences in UI Automation in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

In order to test my app i need to switch on and switch off the WIFI, bluetooth etc.Is there a way to go to settings/preferences to turn my wifi on/off using UI Automation in IOS.

Comment: I would try dorit's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828552/programmatically-turn-on-off-wifi-on-real-ios-device-with-ui-automation

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to perform an external task, use [performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIAutomation/Reference/UIAHostClassReference/UIAHost/UIAHost.html).

With a simple command you can switch off the network like:

```
ifconfig eth0 down
```

Use this as parameter. For a specific process I recommend to use [TCPBlock](http://tcpblock.wordpress.com/). (Call `tcpblock -a appname`.)

Comment: performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout runs on the host computer, not on the iOS device, therefore I don't think this is what is being asked for.

Comment: For a simulator, this is a good approach. For real devices, I'm afraid, there isn't any possibility to do that.