# Programmatically turn on/off wifi on real iOS device with UI Automation

Tags: ios, wifi, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I have already read once or twice that turn on/off wifi on a real iOS device (iPad in my case) with a UI Automation script seems not possible.

I've also read that you can create a script with the target "Settings" but it seems that it's only for simulators, am I right ?

Do you have any ideas or solutions for me ?

Regards,

Comment: You can't unless jailbreak.

Comment: Are you going to create automation test-cases with wifi ON and OFF?

Comment: @Injectios : Yes I could create tests with wifi on and off but there is some contains to download within the app and wifi will be required.

Answer (score 4):

i was able to do so (just make sure you target application is on foremost state when doing so):

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();

target.dragFromToForDuration({x:0.1, y:557.00}, {x:211.00, y:206.00},
0.5); //to expose the actions panel on iOS

target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().elements()["Wifi"].tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:0.44, y:0.47}});
```

Comment: it works! for my iPhone 4s starting point should be {x:0.1, y:477.00}

Comment: the only constraint would be it only works on iOS with action panel.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, like @Larme states, the user's iOS device must be jailbroken due to the locked-down nature of iOS.